# How does latex completely color cross-line fields？

Tags: view, colors, latex

My problem is about latex
My code is as follows

```
\documentclass{mcmthesis}
\mcmsetup{CTeX = false,    % 使用 CTeX 套装时，设置为 true
    tcn = {0000000}, problem = \textcolor{red}{A},
    sheet = true, titleinsheet = true, keywordsinsheet = true,
    titlepage = false, abstract = false}

\usepackage{newtxtext}     % \usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}   % for RStudio Complie
\usepackage{booktabs} % 用于制作三线表
\usepackage{tabularx} % 用于制作自适应表格
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl} % 用于调整颜色
\usepackage{float}%提供float浮动环境
\usepackage{booktabs}%提供命令\toprule、\midrule、\bottomrule
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{6pt}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hspace*{\fill}\Large\bfseries Contents \hspace*{\fill}}

\title{Enjoy a Cozy and Green Bath}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \caption{\textbf{KPIs}}
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % 增加行高
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{0.25\textwidth}|X|}
            
            \hline
            \rowcolor[HTML]{BDD6EE} % 更改第一行的背景颜色
            
            \multirow{2}{*}{Data1} 
            &\cellcolor[HTML]{BDD6EE} The weight vector calculated by \\
            & \cellcolor[HTML]{BDD6EE} The score of maturity of DAS \\ % 将子行全部涂色
            \hline
            \rowcolor[HTML]{BDD6EE} % 更改第二行的背景颜色
            \multirow{2}{*}{Data1} & The weight vector calculated by \\
            & \cellcolor[HTML]{BDD6EE}The score of maturity of DAS \\ % 将子行全部涂色
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{Data1} & The weight vector calculated by \\
            & The score of maturity of DAS \\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

One picture is the effect I want to achieve, and the other picture is my current effect

The effect I want is that the cross-row fields are fully colored, that is, look like the example diagram I gave

Comment: Have a look at the `tabularray` package. It makes merging and colouring cells much easier.

Comment: Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  I edit my code. Now it is compilable.I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{mcmthesis}
\mcmsetup{CTeX = false,    % 使用 CTeX 套装时，设置为 true
tcn = {0000000}, problem = \textcolor{red}{A},
sheet = true, titleinsheet = true, keywordsinsheet = true,
titlepage = false, abstract = false}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{\textbf{KPIs}}
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={cX[halign=c]},
      vlines,hlines,
      row{1-2}={blue!10},
      row{3-4}={green!10},
      row{5-6}={yellow!10}
    }
    \SetCell[r=2]{} Data1
        & The weight vector calculated by \\
        & The score of maturity of DAS \\
    \SetCell[r=2]{} Technology
        & The weight vector calculated by \\
        & The score of maturity of DAS \\ 
    \SetCell[r=2]{} Data1
        & The weight vector calculated by \\
        & The score of maturity of DAS \\ 
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}    
\end{document}
```

[image]